# Setting the NSLayoutAttributeLeading Space to Superview programmatically with some warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, adbannerview

I am bringing an `AdBannerView` to the bottom of my app and I'm creating this programmatically because of the use of shared banners (rather than creating it in `Storyboard`). My app works in Portrait and Landscape mode and so in my `viewWillAppear`, I am setting the frame for the `AdBannerView` and I've also tried for the first time to work with `AutoLayout` programmatically but I'm having some issues.

I created the `AdBannerView` as a test in `Storyboard` and managed to apply the `Leading Spaces to Superview`, `Trailing Spaces to Superview` and `Bottom Space to Superview` constraints on the `AdBannerView` and so when I rotated the device, it would show up on the bottom in both Landscape and Portrait.

However, when doing the `AutoLayout` programatically, I'm not getting the same results.

Here's my code:

```
    [self.adBanner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-100, 320, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];

    NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:self.adBanner
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem:self.view
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                       constant:0];

    [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];



    myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.adBanner
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                  toItem:self.view
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                              multiplier:1
                                                constant:0];

    [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];

    myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.adBanner
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                  toItem:self.view
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline
                                              multiplier:1
                                                constant:0];

    [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];
```

What I'm getting in the console is:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017020f0 ADBannerView:0x7fcb014c1860.bottom == UIView:0x7fcb014f9f70.lastBaseline>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb01624280 h=--& v=--& ADBannerView:0x7fcb014c1860.midY == + 957>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb016242f0 h=--& v=--& V:[ADBannerView:0x7fcb014c1860(66)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017039b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fcb014f9f70(768)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb014fa8a0 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcb014f9f70]   (Names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7fcb01619da0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb017020f0 ADBannerView:0x7fcb014c1860.bottom == UIView:0x7fcb014f9f70.lastBaseline>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The device rotates but in Landscape mode, the `AdBannerView` is not shown, probably because it has been moved off-screen.

I've been through a number of tutorials on `AutoLayout` programatically and I honestly just don't get it.

Question:

Is there a way I can pin my `AdBannerView` to the left edge of the screen (Leading), to the right edge of the screen (Trailing) and to the Bottom of the screen (Bottom) programatically, so that when I rotate my iPhone/iPad, the AdBannerView shows there?

This app is iOS 7 and iOS 8 compatible.

Comment: It shows you give leading,trailing and bottom space....but I think you also need to add height of a view to get rid of this...

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to call `[self.adBanner setTranslatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints:NO]`

Second, you will still need either a top offset constraint or a height constraint for the `adBanner` view.

Also, since you are using auto layout, you don't need to set the frame anymore, that will be done automatically by the layouting system.

Let me know if you need more help :)

---

You still need the height constraint. You can use something like:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view(==50)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"view": self.adBanner }]];
```

You can call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` after you have setup all your constraints. Print out the frame for the `adBanner`, after the method call, for debugging purposes, to make sure all is how you want it.

Comment: This is spot on. The first part is even in console output above: ‘If you're seeing `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints` that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the `UIView` property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`’.

Comment: After doing everything mentioned in this answer you still appear to be trying to connect the leading edge of super to the trailing of banner, and the trailing of super to the leading the banner. I guess logically this should flip the banner horizontally but that's probably not the desired effect (and wont't work). Reverse the leading and trailing attributes for the toItem attribute in the first 2 constraints above

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and follow up answers. I really appreciate this! I've got this working, but I want to be sure what I'm doing is actually correct - so I've added the setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntroConstraints to NO after the setFrame. If I removed the setFrame, the banner appeared at the top, and I kept the first constraint as leading, the second as Trailing and the third as Bottom and that works. Do I still need to add a height/top constraint? It seems to work the way I imagine it to, with the rotations, etc.

Comment: You're welcome :) If it does not work as you want once you remove the setFrame, then yes, you still need to add another constraint. Just add a height constraint. I  have updated my answer.